# How to build an Altair layered chart w/ dual axis?

Tags: python, axis, altair

#### Description

This code shows three Altair charts:

1. `scatter`
2. `rate`
3. `line_plot`

#### Goal

The goal is to combine all charts into a layered chart w/ these specifications:

- show the y-axis for both `scatter` and `rate` (ie. dual axis chart)
- facet by `Series`
- show the `line_plot`.

#### Code

```
    import altair as alt
    from vega_datasets import data
    import pandas as pd
    
    source = data.anscombe().copy()
    source['line-label'] = 'x=y'
    source = pd.concat([source,source.groupby('Series').agg(x_diff=('X','diff'), y_diff=('Y','diff'))],axis=1)
    source['rate'] = source.y_diff/source.x_diff
    source['rate-label'] = 'rate of change'
    source['line-label'] = 'line y=x'
    
    source_linear = source.groupby(by=['Series']).agg(x_linear=('X','max'), y_linear=('X', 'max')).reset_index().sort_values(by=['Series'])
    
    source_origin = source_linear.copy()
    source_origin['y_linear'] = 0
    source_origin['x_linear'] = 0
    
    source_linear = pd.concat([source_origin,source_linear]).sort_values(by=['Series'])
    
    source = source.merge(source_linear,on='Series').drop_duplicates()
    
    scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.60).encode(
        x=alt.X('X', title='X'),
        y=alt.Y('Y', title='Y'),
        color='Series:N',
        tooltip=['X','Y','rate']
    )
    
    line_plot = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(color= 'black', strokeDash=[3,8]).encode(
        x=alt.X('x_linear', title = ''),
        y=alt.Y('y_linear', title = ''),
        shape = alt.Shape('line-label', title = 'Break Even'),
        color = alt.value('black')
    )
    
    rate =  alt.Chart(source).mark_line(strokeDash=[5,3]).encode(
        x=alt.X('X', title = 'X'),
        y=alt.Y('rate:Q'),
        color = alt.Color('rate-label',),
        tooltip=['rate','X','Y']
    )
```

#### Current solution

The issue with the current solution is that the `rate` chart's y-axis is not displaying as a dual axis. Any suggestions?

```
    alt.layer(rate,scatter,line_plot).facet(
        'Series:N'
        , columns=2
    ).resolve_scale(
        x='independent',
        y='independent'
    ).display()
```

[image: Issues w/ Dual Axis]

Comment: Unfortunately, multiple nested resolves are not supported in Vega-Lite, so it is not possible to do what you want to do. See https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1800 for one related bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got it, but this probably isn't the best solution. I've followed the method described in the following link where we manually facet the charts:

1. [Thread on Facets](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1934)

To get the dual axis, I just added `.resolve_scale(y='independent')` to the manual step. Below is the solution:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd

source = data.anscombe().copy()
source\['line-label'\] = 'x=y'
source = pd.concat(\[source,source.groupby('Series').agg(x_diff=('X','diff'), y_diff=('Y','diff'))\],axis=1)
source\['rate'\] = source.y_diff/source.x_diff
source\['rate-label'\] = 'rate of change'
source\['line-label'\] = 'line y=x'

source_linear = source.groupby(by=\['Series'\]).agg(x_linear=('X','max'), y_linear=('X', 'max')).reset_index().sort_values(by=\['Series'\])

source_origin = source_linear.copy()
source_origin\['y_linear'\] = 0
source_origin\['x_linear'\] = 0

source_linear = pd.concat(\[source_origin,source_linear\]).sort_values(by=\['Series'\])

source = source.merge(source_linear,on='Series').drop_duplicates()

scatter = alt.Chart().mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.60).encode(
    x=alt.X('X', title='X'),
    y=alt.Y('Y', title='Y'),
    color='Series:N',
    tooltip=\['X','Y','rate'\]
)

line_plot = alt.Chart().mark_line(color= 'black', strokeDash=\[3,8\]).encode(
    x=alt.X('x_linear', title = '', axis=None),
    y=alt.Y('y_linear', title = '', axis=None),
    shape = alt.Shape('line-label', title = 'Break Even'),
    color = alt.value('black')
)

rate =  alt.Chart().mark_line(strokeDash=\[5,3\]).encode(
    x=alt.X('X', title = 'X'),
    y=alt.Y('rate:Q'),
    color = alt.Color('rate-label',),
    tooltip=\['rate','X','Y'\]
)

scatter_rate = alt.layer(scatter, rate, data=source)

chart_generator =  (alt.layer(scatter, rate, line_plot, data = source, title=f"{val}: Duplicated Points w/ Line at Y=X").transform_filter(alt.datum.Series == val).resolve_scale(y='independent') \
             for val in source.Series.unique()) 

chart = alt.concat(*(
    chart_generator
), columns=2).display()
```

[image]